How to find out loaded php-fpm config values in cPanel
AlmaLinux 9 with cPanel.
I've specified global config values on WHM-> Home / Software / MultiPHP Manager.
For max_children I've specified 150.
In the php log I see different values which I think is coming from this domain's config value.

WARNING: [pool username] server reached max_children setting (5),
consider raising it

So global values are not being taken?
How do we find out loaded config values?
